# How to create User-friendly and SEO friendly URL in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

We are working on website where we using AngularJs. Is there any way to make AngularJs user-friendly urls and seo-friendly urls

Want

application/#user/add

to

application/User/Add

In AngularJs.

---

HTML 5 mode convert hash based urls into Query string based url.

like

[image]

Hashbang URL - http://foo.com/#!/bar?baz=23#baz

HTML 5 Mode - http://foo.com/bar?baz=23#baz

But I want make my url like this

http://foo.com/bar/baz/23/baz  (Fully SEO Friendly url)

Answer (score 0):

The default mode is called the Hashbang mode, which has the `#` you do not want. You can enable HTML5 mode with `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

Read more about setting up routing in HTML5 mode here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider

Answer (score 0):

The best solution as far as I am looking for my angularJS website is is AngularJS SEO PreRender: **Node server that uses phantomJS to render a javascript-rendered page as HTML. To be used in conjunction with prerender middleware.**

https://github.com/prerender/prerender